# Libav-tool avconv: Error Creating Filter when Combining Still Images

Tags: pi-3, video

I'm trying to use the Libav tool to collate still images into mp4 file.  I am using it like this

`avconv -r 1 -I *jpg -vcodec libx264 filename.mp4`

The images are named with the date and time and form a timelapse series. However, I get the following errors:

`Error initializing threading and Error creating filter 'null'.`

Am I missing something?  I have used cd to select the correct directory.  Do I need to use sudo before this statement?